# Cut string in dataframe column until certain string but including

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have similar data as the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pagePath':['/my/retour/details/n8hWu7iWtuRXzSvDvCAUZRAlPda6LM/', 
                               '/my/orders/details/151726/', 
                               '/my/retours/retourmethod/']})
print(df)
                                            pagePath
0  /my/retour/details/n8hWu7iWtuRXzSvDvCAUZRAlPda...
1                         /my/orders/details/151726/
2                          /my/retours/retourmethod/
```

What I want to do is to cut the string until (but including) `details`

**Expected output**

```
                    pagePath
0  /my/retour/details/
1  /my/orders/details/
2  /my/retours/retourmethod/
```

**The following works**, but its slow

```
df['pagePath'] = np.where(df.pagePath.str.contains('details'),
                          df.pagePath.apply(lambda x: x[0:x.find('details')+8]), 
                          df.pagePath)

print(df)

                    pagePath
0        /my/retour/details/
1        /my/orders/details/
2  /my/retours/retourmethod/
```

**I tried regex**, but could only get it to work *excluding*:

```
df['pagePath'] = np.where(df.pagePath.str.contains('details'),
                          df.pagePath.str.extract('(.+?(?=details))'), 
                          df.pagePath)

print(df)
      pagePath
0  /my/retour/
1  /my/orders/
2          NaN
```

Plus the regex code returns `NaN`, when the row does not contain `details`

So I feel there's an easier and more elegant way for this. How would I write a regex code to solve my problem? Or is my solution already sufficient?

Comment: Try `df.pagePath.str.replace(r'^(.*?details/).*', r'\1')`

Comment: That worked. What does the `\1` do?

Comment: `\1` is a backreference to Group 1 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is provide a fallback in the regex for when there is no `'details'`:

```
>>> df.pagePath.str.extract('(.+?details/?|.*)')

                           0
0        /my/retour/details/
1        /my/orders/details/
2  /my/retours/retourmethod/
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks elegant and works, could you explain the regex code a bit more?

Comment: Inside the capture group is a regex that attempts to look for the initial portion up to and including ‘details’, and if it can’t find it then it tries ‘.*’ which matches (the entirety of) every string.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. So which part made it `including`? Or other way around, which part in my code made it `excluding`? My code: `.+?(?=details)`

Comment: Regexes include all matched portions by default, you have to tell the regex to not capture a specific portion (i.e., you want the string to match that portion but don’t want that portion to show up in matches). ?= is a lookahead assertion that doesn’t capture

Answer (score 2):

Would you like to try `str.extract`

```
('/'+df.pagePath.str.extract('/(.*)details')+'details')[0].fillna(df.pagePath)
Out[130]: 
0           /my/retour/details
1           /my/orders/details
2    /my/retours/retourmethod/
Name: 0, dtype: object
```